# Swift mutable structs in closure of class and struct behave differently

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, mutable, swift-structs

I have a class(A) that has a struct variable (S). In one function of this class I call a mutating function on struct variable,this function takes a closure. Body of this closure checks the struct variable's name property.

Struct's mutating function in turns calls a function of some class(B). This class's function again takes a closure. In this closure's body mutate the struct, i.e. change the name property, and call the closure that was supplied by the first class.

When the first class (A) closure is called where we are inspecting the struct's name property, it is never changed.

**But** in step 2 if I use a struct (C) instead of class B, I see that inside class A's closure struct is actually changed. Below is the code:

```
class NetworkingClass {
  func fetchDataOverNetwork(completion:()->()) {
    // Fetch Data from netwrok and finally call the closure
    completion()
  }
}

struct NetworkingStruct {
  func fetchDataOverNetwork(completion:()->()) {
    // Fetch Data from netwrok and finally call the closure
    completion()
  }
}

struct ViewModelStruct {

  /// Initial value
  var data: String = "A"

  /// Mutate itself in a closure called from a struct
  mutating func changeFromStruct(completion:()->()) {
    let networkingStruct = NetworkingStruct()
    networkingStruct.fetchDataOverNetwork {
      self.data = "B"
      completion()
    }
  }

  /// Mutate itself in a closure called from a class
  mutating func changeFromClass(completion:()->()) {
    let networkingClass = NetworkingClass()
    networkingClass.fetchDataOverNetwork {
      self.data = "C"
      completion()
    }
  }
}

class ViewController {
  var viewModel: ViewModelStruct = ViewModelStruct()

  func changeViewModelStruct() {
    print(viewModel.data)

    /// This never changes self.viewModel inside closure, Why Not?
    viewModel.changeFromClass {
      print(self.viewModel.data)
    }

    /// This changes self.viewModel inside/outside closure, Why?
    viewModel.changeFromStruct {
      print(self.viewModel.data)
    }
  }
}

var c = ViewController()
c.changeViewModelStruct()
```

Why this different behaviour. I thought the differentiating factor should be whether I use a struct for viewModel or a class. But here it is depending upon whether Networking is a class or structure, that is independent of any ViewController or ViewModel. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: You mean to say, it is not changing the viewModel.data after the call to changeFromClass method ?

Comment: It changes it after changeFromClass (and before changeFromStruct) but this change is just not visible inside changeFromClass closure.

Comment: This is really mindboggling for me. I feel Swift must be trying to do some optimization as per Apple's following note.  `As an optimization, Swift may instead capture and store a copy of a value if that value is not mutated by a closure, and if the value is not mutated after the closure is created.` ..... If you add this line  `self.data = "D" ` after `let networkingClass = NetworkingClass()` and remove 'self.data = "C" ' then it prints 'D'. Also, if you modify 'struct ViewModelStruct' to 'class ViewModelStruct' then it prints 'C'.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have an idea about the behaviour we are getting in the original question. My understanding is derived from the behaviour of inout parameters inside closures.

**Short answer:**

It is related to whether closure that captures value types are escaping or nonescaping. To make this code work do this.

```
class NetworkingClass {
  func fetchDataOverNetwork(@nonescaping completion:()->()) {
    // Fetch Data from netwrok and finally call the closure
    completion()
  }
}
```

**Long answer:**

Let me give some context first.

inout parameters are used to change values outside of the function scope, like in the below code:

```
func changeOutsideValue(inout x: Int) {
  closure = {x}
  closure()
}
var x = 22
changeOutsideValue(&x)
print(x) // => 23
```

Here x is passed as inout parameter to a function. This function changes value of x in a closure, so it is changed outside of it's scope. Now x's value is 23. We all know this behaviour when we use reference types. But for value types inout parameters are pass by value. So here x is pass by value in the function, and marked as inout. Before passing x into this function, a copy of x is created and passed. So inside the changeOutsideValue this copy is modified, not the original x. Now when this function returns, this modified copy of x copied back to the original x. So we see x is modified outside only when the function returns. Actually it sees that if after changing the inout parameter if the function returns or not i.e. the closure that is capturing x is escaping kind or nonescaping kind.

When the closure is of escaping type, i.e. it just capture the copied value, but before the function returns it is not called. Look at the below code:

```
func changeOutsideValue(inout x: Int)->() -> () {
  closure = {x}
  return closure
}
var x = 22
let c= changeOutsideValue(&x)
print(x) // => 22
c()
print(x) // => 22
```

Here function is capturing the copy of x in a escaping closure for future usages and returns that closure. So when function returns it writes the unchanged copy of x back to x (value is 22). If you print x, it is still 22. If you call the returned closure, it changes the local copy inside closure and it is never copied to outside x, so outside x is still 22.

**So it all depends whether the closure where you are changing the inout parameter is of escaping or non escaping type. If it is nonescaping, changes are seen outside, if it is escaping they are not.**

So coming back to our original example. This is the flow:

1. ViewController calls viewModel.changeFromClass function on viewModel
   struct, self is the reference of the viewController class instance,
   so it is the same self as we created using `var c = ViewController()`,
   So it same as c.
2. In ViewModel's mutating

   ```
   func changeFromClass(completion:()->())
   ```

   we create a Networking class
   instance and pass a closure to fetchDataOverNetwork function. Notice
   here that for changeFromClass function the closure that
   fetchDataOverNetwork takes is of escaping type, because
   changeFromClass makes no assumption that the closure passed in
   fetchDataOverNetwork will be called or not before changeFromClass
   returns.
3. The viewModel self that is captured inside the
   fetchDataOverNetwork's closure is actually a copy of viewModel self.
   So self.data = "C" is actually changing the copy of viewModel, not
   the same instance that is hold by the viewController.
4. You can verify this if you put all the code inside a swift file and emit SIL
   (Swift Intermediate Language). Steps for this are at the end of this
   answer. It becomes clear that capturing viewModel self in
   fetchDataOverNetwork closure prevents viewModel self from being
   optimized to stack. This means that instead of using alloc_stack,
   the viewModel self variable is allocated using alloc_box:

   > %3 = alloc_box $ViewModelStruct, var, name "self", argno 2 // users:
   >   %4,
   >       %11, %13, %16, %17
5. When we print self.viewModel.data in changeFromClass closure it is printing the viewModel's data that is hold by the viewController, not the copy that is being changed by the fetchDataOverNetwork closure. And since the fetchDataOverNetwork closure is of escaping type and viewModel's data is used (printed) before changeFromClass function could return, changed viewModel is not copied to original viewModel (viewController's).
6. Now as soon as changeFromClass method returns changed viewModel is copied back to the original viewModel, so if you do "print(self.viewModel.data)" just after changeFromClass call, you see the value is changed. (this is because though fetchDataOverNetwork is assumed to be of escaping type, at runtime it is actually turn out to be of nonescaping type)

Now as @san pointed out in comments that "If you add this line self.data = "D" after let networkingClass = NetworkingClass() and remove 'self.data = "C" ' then it prints 'D'". This also make sense because self outside the closure is exact self that is hold by the viewController, since you removed self.data = "C" inside closure, there is no capturing of viewModel self. On the other hand if you don't remove self.data = "C" then it captures a copy of self. In this case print statement prints C. Check that.

This explains the behaviour of changeFromClass, but what about changeFromStruct that is working properly? In theory same logic should be applied to changeFromStruct and things should not work. But as it turns out (by emitting SIL for changeFromStruct function) the viewModel self value captured in networkingStruct.fetchDataOverNetwork function is same self as outside of the closure, so everywhere the same viewModel self is modified:

> debug_value_addr %1 : $*ViewModelStruct, var, name "self", argno 2 //
>   id: %2

**This is confusing and I have no explanation to this. But this is what I found. At least it clears the air about changefromClass behaviour.**

**Demo code Solution:**

For this demo code the solution to make changeFromClass work as we expect is to make fetchDataOverNetwork function's closure nonescaping like so:

```
class NetworkingClass {
  func fetchDataOverNetwork(@nonescaping completion:()->()) {
    // Fetch Data from netwrok and finally call the closure
    completion()
  }
}
```

This tells changeFromClass function that before it returns passed closure (that is capturing viewModel self) will be called for sure so there is no need to do alloc_box and make a separate copy.

**Real scenario Solutions:**

In reality fetchDataOverNetwork will make a web service request and return. When response comes then the completion will be called. So it will always be of escaping type. This will create the same issue. Some ugly solutions for this could be:

1. Make ViewModel a class not struct. This makes sure that viewModel
   self is a reference and same everywhere. But I don't like it, though
   all the sample code on internet about MVVM uses class for viewModel.
   In my opinion major code of an iOS app will be ViewController,
   ViewModel and Models and if all of these are classes then you really
   doesn't use value types.
2. Make ViewModel a struct. From mutating function return a new mutated
   self, either as return value or inside completion depending on your
   use case:

   ```
   /// ViewModelStruct
   mutating func changeFromClass(completion:(ViewModelStruct)->()){
   let networkingClass = NetworkingClass()
   networkingClass.fetchDataOverNetwork {
     self.data = "C"
     self = ViewModelStruct(self.data)
     completion(self)
   }
   }
   ```

   In this case caller have to always make sure it assigns the returned value to it's original instance, like so:

   ```
   /// ViewController
   func changeViewModelStruct() {
       viewModel.changeFromClass { changedViewModel in
         self.viewModel = changedViewModel
         print(self.viewModel.data)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Make ViewModel a struct. Declare a closure variable in struct and call it with self from every mutating function. Caller will provide the body of this closure.

   ```
   /// ViewModelStruct
   var viewModelChanged: ((ViewModelStruct) -> Void)?

   mutating func changeFromClass(completion:()->()) {
   let networkingClass = NetworkingClass()
   networkingClass.fetchDataOverNetwork {
     self.data = "C"
     viewModelChanged(self)
     completion(self)
   }
   }

   /// ViewController
   func viewDidLoad() {
       viewModel = ViewModelStruct()
       viewModel.viewModelChanged = { changedViewModel in
         self.viewModel = changedViewModel
       }
   }

   func changeViewModelStruct() {
       viewModel.changeFromClass {
         print(self.viewModel.data)
       }
   }
   ```

Hope I am clear in my explaination. I know it is confusing, so you will have to read and try this multiple times.

Some of the resources I referred are [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/03/27/on-delete.html), [here](https://developer.ibm.com/swift/2016/01/27/seven-swift-snares-how-to-avoid-them/) and [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0035-limit-inout-capture.md).

Last one is a accepted swift proposal in 3.0 about removing this confusion. I am not sure if this is it is implemented in swift 3.0 or not.

**Steps to emit SIL:**

1. Put all your code in a swift file.
2. Go to terminal and do this:

   > swiftc -emit-sil StructsInClosure.swift > output.txt
3. Look at output.txt, search for methods you want to see.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem while following MVVM model. Thank for the detail explanation.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground


protocol ViewModel {
  var delegate: ViewModelDelegate? { get set }
}

protocol ViewModelDelegate {
  func viewModelDidUpdated(model: ViewModel)
}

struct ViewModelStruct: ViewModel {
  var data: Int = 0
  var delegate: ViewModelDelegate?

  init() {
  }

  mutating func fetchData() {
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!) {
       result in
      self.data = 20
      self.delegate?.viewModelDidUpdated(self)
      print("viewModel.data in fetchResponse : \(self.data)")

      XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
      }.resume()
  }
}

protocol ViewModeling {
  associatedtype Type
  var viewModel: Type { get }
}

typealias ViewModelProvide = protocol<ViewModeling, ViewModelDelegate>

class ViewController: ViewModelProvide {
  var viewModel = ViewModelStruct() {
    didSet {
      viewModel.delegate = self
      print("ViewModel in didSet \(viewModel)")
    }
  }

  func viewDidLoad() {
    viewModel = ViewModelStruct()
  }

  func changeViewModelStruct() {
    print(viewModel)
    viewModel.fetchData()
  }
}

extension ViewModelDelegate where Self: ViewController {
  func viewModelDidUpdated(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel as! ViewModelStruct
  }
}

var c = ViewController()
c.viewDidLoad()
c.changeViewModelStruct()
```

In your solution 2, 3, it need to assign new View Model in ViewController. So I wanna make it automatically by using Protocol Extension. didSet observer works well! But this need to remove force casting in delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but with this code we can see that the `ViewController's`, `viewModel.data` is properly set for both class and struct cases. What is different is that the `viewModel.changeFromClass` closure captures a stale `self.viewModel.data`. Notice in particular that only the '3 self' print for class is wrong. Not the '2 self' and '4 self' prints wrapping it.

[image]

```
class NetworkingClass {
  func fetchDataOverNetwork(completion:()->()) {
    // Fetch Data from netwrok and finally call the closure
    print("\nclass: \(self)")
    completion()
  }
}

struct NetworkingStruct {
  func fetchDataOverNetwork(completion:()->()) {
    // Fetch Data from netwrok and finally call the closure
    print("\nstruct: \(self)")
    completion()
  }
}

struct ViewModelStruct {

  /// Initial value
  var data: String = "A"

  /// Mutate itself in a closure called from a struct
  mutating func changeFromStruct(completion:()->()) {
    let networkingStruct = NetworkingStruct()
    networkingStruct.fetchDataOverNetwork {
      print("1 \(self)")
      self.data = "B"
      print("2 \(self)")
      completion()
      print("4 \(self)")
    }
  }

  /// Mutate itself in a closure called from a class
  mutating func changeFromClass(completion:()->()) {
    let networkingClass = NetworkingClass()
    networkingClass.fetchDataOverNetwork {
      print("1 \(self)")
      self.data = "C"
      print("2 \(self)")
      completion()
      print("4 \(self)")
    }
  }
}

class ViewController {
  var viewModel: ViewModelStruct = ViewModelStruct()

  func changeViewModelStruct() {
    print(viewModel.data)

    /// This never changes self.viewModel, Why Not?
    viewModel.changeFromClass {
      print("3 \(self.viewModel)")
      print(self.viewModel.data)
    }

    /// This changes self.viewModel, Why?
    viewModel.changeFromStruct {
      print("3 \(self.viewModel)")
      print(self.viewModel.data)
    }
  }
}

var c = ViewController()
c.changeViewModelStruct()
```

Comment: Precisely my point. We can verify this by printing self.viewModel.data after viewModel.changeFromClass (before viewModel.changeFromStruct) , it prints "C". So call to viewModel.changeFromClass actually changing viewModel but it is not visible inside the closure. My guess is that inside viewModel.changeFromClass closure self.viewModel is captured in it's current state, that is ViewModelStruct(data: "A") and that is what we are printing. mutating function of ViewModel is changing struct that is visible to viewController but not that is visible to closure.

Comment: You should consider fetchDataOverNetwork function will async not a sync. I edited it async, view model in class is not changed.`1 ViewModelStruct(data: "A")
2 ViewModelStruct(data: "B")
3 ViewModelStruct(data: "A")
A
4 ViewModelStruct(data: "B")
`

Comment: @tarun_sharma Did you solve it? I think mutating function changed the value right after function returns. So when using async func (like fetch data over network), value in view controller changed right after mutating function(new value assigned). From network function's completion, it changed data in original value, not a new value. I faced same situation, and not found solution yet. If you have find a solution, would you post it? It makes me crazy. :(

Comment: @Paul Yes you are right. I have a solution in mind, where you return the mutated struct back in the completion handler. In this case Caller have to make sure to assign the mutated value type back to it's instance. Another solution could be to have a structUpdated closure in value type. This closure's body is assigned by the caller and every mutating function in struct has to make sure it calls that closure before it calls the completion handler. These are ugly solutions but this is only I got so far.

Comment: Besides this I think I have an understanding why the original behaviour. This is on the lines you said where value types are copied and that copy is modified inside mutating function, and once that function returns this mutated copy is copied back to the original value. I'll post my understanding in detail shortly.